# sql data reader class

Tags: asp.net, sql

I did sql command with `SqlDataReader` but I had this error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: UserName

**Page Load event:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {

        SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("Total", con);
        Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader Dr = Com.ExecuteReader();
        if (Dr.Read())
        {
            string Result= Dr["UserName"].ToString();
            Lbltotal.Text = Result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
Alter proc Total
as
begin
select Count (UserName) from Registration 
end
```

Comment: And what is your question? You haven't shown your stored procedure. What is the returned resultset from it? Is there a `UserName` column in it? Obviously not hence the exception.

Comment: Yes, you need to include the stored procedure in your question and also check whether you actually have a `UserName` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your storder procedure to:

```
Alter proc Total
as
begin
select Count (UserName) as UserName from Registration 
end
```

Comment: Which might work, but it's a really bad naming, to call a **count of usernames** just `UserName` - this will make it harder in the future to maintain this code. Avoid it whenever possible - if it's a count, call it a count!

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning any column called `UserName` - you're just returning a count which has no explicit column name.

If you have something like this - just a single value - you could also use the `ExecuteScalar` method which will return exactly one value:

```
using(SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("Total", con))
{
    Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    int count = (int)Com.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

If you insist on using the `SqlDataReader`, you just need to use a positional parameter:

```
using(SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("Total", con))
{
    Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using(SqlDataReader Dr = Com.ExecuteReader())
    {
       if (Dr.Read())
       {
           string Result= Dr[0].ToString(); // take value no. 0 - the first one
           Lbltotal.Text = Result;
       }
    }
}
```